# case-sensitive queries in MySQL

Tags: mysql, case-sensitive

I have a table with a column named "Shortcut". I want these IDs to be case-sensitive (so say shortcut myshortcut is different from Myshortcut).

Right now, when I select a row with the shortcut, it is not case sensitive. So in my example above, both shortcuts refer to the same field.

What can I do?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use one of the [binary types (`varbinary`)](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/binary-varbinary.html) instead of the text (`varchar`) types. Alternatively, change the collation on the text column to binary (`column_name varchar(16) binary`). See the [documentation on binary collations](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/charset-binary-collations.html).